# datetimepicker change display without format

Tags: node.js, momentjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have a form in which I use the bootstrap datetimepicker.

html:

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1' style="width:35%">
<input type='text' class="form-control" id="prodStart" name="prodStart" required=""/>
<span class="input-group-addon">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>
```

javascript:

```
var dateTimeSettings = {
    format: 'dd  DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A'
  }
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker(dateTimeSettings);
```

I recently changed the format to the above as I did not like the display of the default format.

My problem occurs when I POST the data, `req.body.prodStart` now returns a String, not a date object ( ISO() ) which I was previously getting and have built my application code around.

If I change the `dateTimeSettings` to `{}` the `req.body.prodStart` returns an object. This is what I want in the back end but now the user sees an undesired format when filling out the form.

How can I keep the object format in `req.body.prodStart` and `dd  DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A` display format in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can save ISO 8601 formatted date in a hidden field:

```
<input type='hidden' id="prodStart" name="prodStart" />
```

This field should be updated on every date change:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').on('dp.change', function(e) {
  $('#prodStart').val(e.date.format());
})
```

The hidden field with ISO date will be posted to a server while the text input will contain the date in your custom format.

Please see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdyxLs1j/).